# How to load Metacello in Squeak?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, repository, metacello

It is known that Metacello first or main target was Pharo, but it seems now that [Squeak 4 is supported](https://github.com/dalehenrich/metacello-work/blob/master/docs/MetacelloScriptingAPI.md). I've tried but fails due a missing method. From the Transcript:

```
Starting atomic load
    Loaded -> OSProcess-dtl.65 --- http://www.squeaksource.com/OSProcess --- cache
Finished atomic load
BaselineOf>>projectClass (MetacelloMCBaselineProject is Undeclared) 
ConfigurationOf>>versionNumberClass (MetacelloSemanticVersionNumber is Undeclared) 
Loaded -> Metacello-Base-dkh.103 --- http://seaside.gemstone.com/ss/metacello --- cache
MetacelloProjectRegistration>>version (MetacelloMCBaselineProject is Undeclared) 
MetacelloBaselineSpecGenerator>>projectSpecCreationBlock (MetacelloMCBaselineProject is Undeclared) 
Loaded -> Metacello-Core-dkh.667 --- http://seaside.gemstone.com/ss/metacello --- cache
Loaded -> Metacello-MC-dkh.666 --- http://seaside.gemstone.com/ss/metacello --- cache
Loaded -> Metacello-ToolBox-dkh.131 --- http://seaside.gemstone.com/ss/metacello --- cache
Loaded -> Metacello-FileTree-dkh.29 --- http://seaside.gemstone.com/ss/metacello --- cache
Loaded -> Metacello-GitHub-dkh.22 --- http://seaside.gemstone.com/ss/metacello --- cache
Evaluated -> 1.0-beta.32 [ConfigurationOfMetacello] >> metacelloPrimeRegistry
...finished 1.0-beta.32
...RETRY->ConfigurationOfMetacelloPreview
...RETRY->ConfigurationOfMetacelloPreview
gofer repository error: 'GoferRepositoryError: My subclass should have overridden #downloadFile:to:'...ignoring
...FAILED->ConfigurationOfMetacelloPreview
```

I am using Squeak 4.4-12327 image. Any help on this?

Comment: I may add that Metacello has never had a main or first target. It was from the start intended to be cross-platform, with GemStone, Pharo, and Squeak being supported from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above solution is no longer valid

u need to get it using this below code

```
(Installer monticello http:'http://seaside.gemtalksystems.com/ss')
project: 'metacello';
install: 'ConfigurationOfMetacello'. 

((Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfMetacello) project 
  latestVersion) load.
```

Comment: This also does not work anymore with the current version `Squeak5.1-16548-32bit.image`. Neither does the command listed at https://github.com/dalehenrich/metacello-work#squeak, all throw exceptions, too much to paste here.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this (as proposed by the install doc on Github) in 4.4 and had no problems whatsoever:

```
Installer gemsource
project: 'metacello';
install: 'ConfigurationOfMetacello'. 

((Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfMetacello) project 
  version: '1.0-beta.32') load.
```

What code are you using?

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was using the script provided in the link.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, by now, the Metacello installation is integrated into Squeak since Squeak 5.3 (maybe earlier).

To load Metacello via the UI, open the Apps menu in the main docking bar, and choose the Preference Wizard. Press Done and in the next view, choose Metacello for installation.

To load Metacello from code, evaluate `Metacello new` or `Installer ensureRecentMetacello` in any workspace/CodeHolder.